# Drawing 3D points in Matlab and connect them in order via line

Tags: matlab, mesh, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I have an array that contains 3D float points. Not only I want to depict them in a figure but also I want to connect them with lines.

Example) lets say we have array called X:

```
X=[0, 0, 0; 0.48, -0.88, 0.09; -1.06, 0.55, 0.9; -0.65, 1.5, -1.44; 1.1, 0.59,
-1.11;0.76, 0.86, -0.52; -1.08, -0.28, 0.55; 1.47, -1.21, 0.14; 1.42, -2.15, 0.71; -0.64,  
1.87, 2.4;2.32, -2.44, 2.02; 2.25, -2.56, -3.03; 2.35, 2.65, -1.5; 0.23, -2.25, 2.78; 2.47,  
-3.12,  -1.91; 2.27, 1.37, -3.05; 2.3, 1.9, -1.29; -1.77, -0.51, 2.33];  

    X1= [0,0,0]  
    X2=[0.48, -0.88, 0.09]  
    X3=[-1.06, 0.55, 0.9] ...
```

now I want that X1...Xn to be drawn in figure as points then X1 get connected to X2, X2 get connected to X3, X3 get connected to X4, etc

how could I do that?

Here is what I ve done but I get a wrong figure:

```
figure;hold on;  
    P=[];  
    for i=1:size(X,1)  
    x=X(i,1);  
    y=X(i,2);  
    z=X(i,3);  
    A=[ x,y,z];  
    P=vertcat(P,A);  
    plot(P);  
    end
```

And Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Note - `matplotlib` is not the same as plotting in `matlab`, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`plot3` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html).

In particular, `plot3(X, Y, Z)` will plot the points and join them with a line.

In your case:

```
plot3(X(:, 1), X(:, 2), X(:, 3))
```

Comment: @ mathematical.coffe : 
1. Just for my clarification- Does plot3(X(:, 1), X(:, 2), X(:, 3)) means that for all 3D points(v1,v2,v3) that each is in a row, connect them together? 

2. how could I give axis a name on the plot?

Comment: `plot3(X, Y, Z)` plots the points with X coordinates `X`, Y coordinates `Y`, and Z coordinates `Z`, joining them together (read the documentation for further information; I provided the link in the answer). At the bottom of the documentation is an example which also sets the axis names, so you could see how to do it from there.

Comment: Thanks,here is the answer:

plot3(X(:, 1),X(:, 2), X(:, 3));  
xlabel('X');  
ylabel('Y');  
zlabel('Z');  
grid on;